# how to load existing webview in alert dialog android

Tags: java, android, webview, dialog, layout-inflater

I have loaded a webview by default, with settings and url at the bottom of the page, i need to display that existing webview in an alert dialog box.
I don't want to create new webview since i need to maintain the state of the existing webview (i mean if i had clicked on the button inside the webivew and toggled the content, then i need to show the exact same content in alert dialog)
I tried to inflate by moving the webview along with some textview in seperate layout but it on alert dialog it shows textview but webview is not loaded.
Suggestions welcome!!

Comment: Can you post your code? Also why would webview be neded in the alert dialog?

Comment: In the webview , i may click a button and open modal to show content but it will be displayed inside the webview's width and height right, i want to display the modal like native modal . so i try to load the existing webveiw on the dialog and show only the modal and hide remaining contents.
they will call my function onclosing and opening modal so that i can do this hiding stuff and display like native modal dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, i assume your question is to reuse an existing web view from a layout and display it in alert dialog box.
If so you can remove web view from the original layout and add it in alert dialog as follows

```
WebView myWebview = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) myWebview.getParent();
if (parent != null) {                            
   parent.removeView(myWebview);
}
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
AlertDialog alert;
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert = builder.create();
alert.setView(myWebview);
alert.show();
```

so the existing webview will be removed from its layout and displayed on the alert dialog.
You can also do the vice versa (remove webview from alert dialog and append in the previous layout.

Comment: thanks this is what im looking for  along with this i will do the width , height and hiding things. thanks a lot